# No entiendo este código de java

Tags: java, array

Soy novata estudiando java y en apuntes he encontrado el siguiente código (un código que sé que es sencillo, pero mi cabeza no lo racionaliza todavía, y quería ver si me podríais ayudar un poco...):

```
public static Clasificable[] clasificar(Clasificable[] array) {
    int i, j;
    Clasificable c;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j].compare(array[i]) == Clasificable.INFERIOR) {
                c = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = c;
            } else if (array[j].compare(array[i]) == Clasificable.ERROR) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

¿Por qué creamos `i` y `j` exactamente? ¿Por qué le sumaríamos un 1 a la `i` en el segundo `for`? Sí, sé que son preguntas bastante tontas, pero de verdad que mi mente aún no ha llegado ahí, y me gustaría comprenderlo y llegar, así que si alguien ve la necesidad de explicarmelo como a un niño de 4 años, le pido por favor que lo haga...

El valor de INFERIOR, etc sería:

```
public static final int INFERIOR=-1;
public static final int IGUAL=0;
public static final int SUPERIOR=1;
public static final int ERROR=-99;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes un array que quieres recorrer:

```
for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
   //haces algo con array[i] ...
}
```

Ahora imagina que quieres, para cada posición, hacer una operación con el resto de posiciones posteriores: Eso significa que para cada posición, quieres volver a recorrer el array. Si `i` indica la posición del elemento actual, creas `j` para recorrer las posiciones del resto de elementos. Y como quieres empezar con la posición justo después del actual, pues lo más fácil es sumarle uno a ésta:

```
// estoy en la posicion i y quiero recorrer el resto
for(int j= i+1;j< array.length;j++) { //j empieza valiendo i + 1
   ...
}
```

Si unes los dos bucles, anidándolos, tendrás un código como el que has puesto.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, lo he entendido mucho mejor!

Comment: @Lena Por favor, marca como *aceptada* (haz click sobre el *check* que sale al lado) alguna de las respuestas para que la pregunta quede marcada como *respondida*. No es obligatorio pero ayuda a mantener el sitio *ordenado*

Comment: Siento muchísimo lo que he tardado en dar el check... muchas gracias de nuevo, y lo siento. Se entiende perfectamente.

Answer (score 6):

Es una implementación del [algoritmo de ordenación por inserción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_por_inserci%C3%B3n).

Usamos `i` y `j` porque hay dos bucles anidados, el externo recorre todo el array y el interno recorre, para cada valor de `i`, el resto del array para ver si encuentra un valor menor que el de la posición `i` para reemplazarlo si lo encuentra.

`Clasificable` parece simplemente una extensión de `java.util.Comparable` a la que se le han añadido cuatro valores constantes con los valores que devuelve `java.util.Comparable.compare(Object)`. No es muy útil, y lía más de lo que ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Juan! Leyendo las dos respuestas hasta ahora me ha quedado más claro.